# IAsyncResult to Byte[] transformation

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-core

Following [This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient.beginreceive?view=net-5.0) I created a similar code:

```
    public struct UDPState
    {
        public UdpClient UDPClient;
        public IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint;
    }
    public static void receiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        UdpClient u = ((UDPState)(ar.AsyncState)).UDPClient;
        IPEndPoint e = ((UDPState)(ar.AsyncState)).RemoteIpEndPoint;

        byte[] receiveBytes = u.EndReceive(ar, ref e);
    }
    public Byte[] UDPSMClientReceive(UdpClient client, IPEndPoint ip)
    {
        try
        {
            UDPState state = new UDPState();
            state.UDPClient = client;
            state.RemoteIpEndPoint = ip;
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(Convert.ToInt32(refreshTime));

                IAsyncResult receivedBytes = UDPClient.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(receiveCallback), state);

                return receivedBytes;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("ERROR!! Se han generado errores en la configuración UDP o en la recepción de paquetes: " + e);
        }
    }
```

I need to return a Byte[] instead of IAsyncResult, I've looked around but I couldn't find any documentation on it. Is there a way to accomplish this or am I missing something?

Comment: `IAsyncResult` is not the result, it represents the asynchronous call. Don't use the ancient `Begin/End` methods, use the asynchronous methods like [ReceiveAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient.receiveasync?view=net-5.0). This way you can write just `var result=await client.ReceiveAsync(); var bytes=result.Buffer;`

Answer (score 2):

`IAsyncResult` is not the result, it represents the asynchronous call. The Begin/End methods were used in the [Asynchronous Programming Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/asynchronous-programming-model-apm) used *before* tasks were introduced in 2010. By now, especially in .NET Core, almost all classes use tasks.

You can use [ReceiveAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient.receiveasync?view=net-5.0) instead. This way you can simplify your method to:

```
public async Task<Byte[]> UDPSMClientReceive(UdpClient client)
{
    try
    {
        var sleep=Convert.ToInt32(refreshTime);
        state.RemoteIpEndPoint = ip;
        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(sleep);
            var result=await UdpClient.ReceiveAsync();
            return result.Buffer;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception(e,"ERROR!! Se han generado errores en la configuración UDP o en la recepción de paquetes: " + e.Message);
    }
}
```

I changed the exception handler to include the original exception as an inner exception. After that, there's no need to include the entire original exception in the message.

Asynchronous IO operations don't use a thread. Once they complete, execution continues on a threadpool thread, so `Thread.Sleep` should be avoided